# How to use insert and select simultaneously?

Tags: sql-server

I have table test and it has columns id,name and age.I want the id so I am querying like
it

```
select id from test where age=12
```

After I get the id I am updating the name using update query

Now lets say if age=13 not present then I will insert a row(`insert into test(age) values(13)`) and after it is inserted I will get the id(as id is `autoincremented`).So is it possible to do insert and select simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

> So is it possible to do insert and select simultaneously?

Yes, you can use the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause of the [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) statement.

```
insert into dbo.Test(age) 
output inserted.ID 
values(13);
```